# drupal view node posted field

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a  view where i need to use the node posted as a field. It will show all the nodes which have been posted in descending order. How can i do that? I have only been successful with node update . But i want node post date as the field

Comment: You say you have only been successful with Node: Update, please give more information on what you did to get Node: Update to work and what you have tried to do for node posted that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To make a view that will show a list of *all* nodes in descending order by the node's post date:

Assuming you are using a plain node such as "story":

1. Create a new view, name it whatever you like
2. In the "Fields" box click the "+" to add all the fields ("Node: Title", "Node: Body", "Node: Post date") Add any other fields you would like to see displayed.
3. For each field choose the settings you want to use and click "Update"
4. In the "sort criteria" box (upper right of view UI) also click the "+", add "Node: Post date", choose "Descending" then click "Update"
5. Save the changes to your view

This will give you a very basic list of all your nodes ordered by newest to oldest.  You could also do this for specific content types if needed by adding a "Node: type" filter.

Comment: I added all the above. But it does not show the date. Is there a particular date format i should use?

Comment: The date format shouldn't matter other than personal preference.  With all of the basic settings, the output should look something like this `Title: Test Node 1
Body:
Post date: 02/28/2011 - 3:43pm
Title: Test Node 2
Body:
Post date: 02/28/2011 - 3:42pm` etc.  Do you see any node information returned in the display for your view?